# what is difference between npm install vs npm install --save?

Tags: npm

when I installed node_module on my project.

1. with `npm install`

   - I changed

     "dependencies": { "own_module": "github:own_module#v1.0"}
     to

     "dependencies": { "own_module": "github:own_module#v**2.0**"}

     on package.json.

     and execute `npm install` then, package-lock.json file changed.
     but, it's hash value not changed..

     "own_module": {
     "version": "1.0",
     "resolved": "git+ssh://git@github.com/own_module.git#diakvjj"}

     to

     "own_module": {
     "version": "**2.0**",
     "resolved": "git+ssh://git@github.com/own_module.git#**diakvjj**"}
2. with `npm install --save github:own_module#v2.0"`

   - this changed package.json  automatically

     "dependencies": { "own_module": "github:own_module#v1.0"}
     to

     "dependencies": { "own_module": "github:own_module#v**2.0**"}

     and then, package-lock.json file correctly.

     "own_module": {
     "version": "1.0",
     "resolved": "git+ssh://git@github.com/own_module.git#diakvjj"}

     to

     "own_module": {
     "version": "**2.0**",
     "resolved": "git+ssh://git@github.com/own_module.git#**awerfd**"}

why npm install could not change package-lock.json file automatically?

Now, I use npm@8.3.1 *(meaning, version 8)*

Answer (score 0):

–save or -S: When the following command is used with npm install this will save all your installed core packages into the dependency section in the package.json file. Core dependencies are those packages without which your application will not give desired results. But as mentioned earlier, it is an unnecessary feature in the npm 5.0.0 version onwards.
read more on this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-meaning-of-save-for-npm-install/#:%7E:text=But%20the%20fact%20is%20there,the%20installed%20package%20to%20package.)

Comment: I am using Npm8. However, the result of npm Install vs npm install --save is different like my question..